# How to get the phone application new file type to show up? (eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed the eclipse for android developers, when I launch it, it says that it is neon 3. I have installed the android 6 and the deafult packages from the SDK manager. When I try to create a new phone application file (acording to yourtube tutorials) it just simply doesn't show up. There are some phone related things in there, look at the screenshot. [image]

### Things that I have aleready tried:

-waiting 
-restarting my PC 
(I will edit this when I get an answer and it doesn't work)

### My PC specifics:

-Windows 10 64-bit
(request some more specifications in the comments if you need any)
Also some of my built in tutorials don't work (I will put a link to that question after I post it)

Comment: any reason for not using android studio?

Comment: @VivekMishra I don't want to be limited to android only. and for one bug or misunderstanding I'm not ditching a whole software

Comment: Android Studio is built on Intellij. It works with many languages

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm using windows 10 and developing for android

Comment: So? Android Studio runs on all operating systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try to create a new phone application file

That was never a menu option, AFAIK.

Android Activity is clearly visible, though.

Or new Project, and select Android Application from there

Comment: Wow, it actually worked thanks, I will accept the answer in 10 minutes